# xenv shell changing into sub-shell

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I am writing a ksh to checkout the code and setup the compilation variables through xenv setup. This is how my script looks at the moment -

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
logname=$LOGNAME
homedir="$HOME/${logname}-SVN-Dev/pkgroot"

#Create directory <username>-SVN-Dev to contain copied code.
if [ -z "$logname" ]
then
    logname=`/usr/ucb/whoami`
fi

RunCmd "rm -rf $homedir"
RunCmd "mkdir -p $homedir"

## Some code to checkout code

cd $HOME
echo "setenv PKGROOT $homedir">>$HOME/.cshrc
echo "setenv DEVROOT $homedir/src">>$HOME/.cshrc
source $HOME/.cshrc

RunCmd "/xenv/xenv -L -i $homedir/My.env $homedir;"
make -f project.mk createmakefile
```

The xenv above switches the shell and goes into a new prompt, ia_cross: and my shell exits without executing the "make -f project.mk createmakefile" command.

I have tries putting a pipe between make and xenv but that didn't solve this. Any suggestions would really help?

Comment: You are trying to run that `make` command in the `xenv` environment?

Comment: In a `ksh` script, you are trying to `source ~/.cshrc`?! That's not likely to work.

Comment: Hacking your `.cshrc` each time you run this command, appending to it, is going to make your `.cshrc` file huge and wasteful over time since you don't remove previous settings from it.  I'm not convinced you should be using C shell in the first place, but that's a separate discussion.  Even if you do use it, you probably should not go editing (I originally wrote 'corrupting', but let's try to stay politically semi-correct) your `.cshrc` file on the fly.  Also, `RunCmd` is not a standard command AFAIK; it isn't clear where it comes from or exactly what it does.

Comment: Is this [`xenv`](https://bitbucket.org/elarson/xenv) the one you're using?  Or is there another?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes I need to run make command in xenv environment after switching to it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I have placed conditions around .cshrc append to see if the variable was not already exported in .cshrc to prevent it from running huge. I have also changed the .cshrc to .kshrc since mine was k-shell. RunCmd is a small subroutine I have written in script to redirect the output of every command I run into /dev/null and exit the script by checking the return status of previous command. The problem I still have is my make does not run in xterm, the script exists the moment it switches to xterm.

Comment: Note that if you redirect output and errors to `/dev/null`, you've no idea what's going wrong.  You should redirect to a file, or syslog, or something so you can see what's going on.  `make` doesn't need an `xterm` to run in; it will run in background quite happily.  It'll be OK with outputs going to `/dev/null`; the problem is that you can't see what's going wrong — not that `make` doesn't like it.  I'm not sure what else to suggest to you.

Comment: Does `xenv` spawn a new xterm window? And you want `make` run inside *that* xterm window? Because this clearly can't do that. But presumably you can stick the `make` command in the quoted argument to `xenv` like the other command you have there, no? (Also show us `RunCmd` and update this to show your current code please.)

Answer (score 0):

use below command in your script,

`echo "make -f project.mk createmakefile" | /xenv/xenv -c -i $homedir/My.env $homedir;`